# New Relic nri flex integration to alert password expiry of users like tomcat fuse wpms oracle

Tags: yaml, newrelic, nrql

I have 1 automation to do through new relic monitoring tool i hato make a custom warning alert integration in new relic to check the password expiry of users like tomcat, fuse, oracle, wpms
Till now I achieved that through creating a yaml file for a single user but i need a single yml for multiple users and i am stuck as there are some limitations under new relic to write the script.

Created a yml file as per the new relic integration and checking the output of that code in new relic query builder

Here is my code, when i am running it giving me syntax error

for user in tomcat fuse wpms oracle do;todaydat=`date +%s`;passexpdate=`chage -l $user | grep "Password expires" | awk -F':' '{print $2}'`;passexp=`date -d "$passexpdate" +%s`;exp=`expr \( $passexp - $todaydat \)`;expday=`expr \( $exp / 86400 \)`;colmnnam=expday;echo "$user $passexp $expday" done

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have pasted the code in the question, getting syntax error while running the code